# data manipulation with na values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

My code are like that df2 DataFrame (toy data) :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

end = '20201117'

np.random.seed(107)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):
    start = np.random.choice(['20000101', '20100101', '20160101', '20121010'])
    df_tempo = pd.DataFrame({'product': 'p'+str(i),
                             'category': 'cat'+str(np.random.choice(4))
                             },
                            index=pd.bdate_range(start=pd.to_datetime(start),
                                                 end=end,
                                                 freq=np.random.choice(['D', 'W'])))

    df_tempo['valeur1'] = np.random.randint(50, 100, df_tempo.shape[0])
    df_tempo['valeur2'] = np.random.randint(100, 200, df_tempo.shape[0])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_tempo])
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'date'})

df2 = df.pivot(index='date', columns=['category', 'product'], values=['valeur1', 'valeur2'])
```

from this I would like to calculate the growth rate for 2020, 2019,..years
I tried :

```
df2.apply([
    lambda x: 100*x.valeur1[x.valeur1['2020'].last_valid_index()]/x.valeur1[x.valeur1['2019'].last_valid_index()]-100, 
         ])
```

but get an error message with is (I would like to calculate different stat for valeur1 and valeur2) :

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'valeur1'
```

so I did (it's not what I would like to do because as I said I would like to apply different stat on valeur1 and valeur2) :

```
df2['valeur1'].apply([
    lambda x: 100*x[x['2020'].last_valid_index()]/x[x['2019'].last_valid_index()]-100, 
    lambda x: 100*x[x['2010'].last_valid_index()]/x[x['2009'].last_valid_index()]-100, 
    
         ])
```

It works except that

```
lambda x: 100*x[x['2010'].last_valid_index()]/x[x['2009'].last_valid_index()]-100
```

because I have data series that have no data for 2010 and so return an error.

I tried then a `dropna()`but not help

Any ideas to help on these 2 problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `date` is already the index of `df2`, `pd.Grouper(freq="Y").last()` can be used to retrieve the value on the last date. Is this what you are expecting?

**Note**: `df2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="Y")).ffill()` will fill the last date of each year with previous valid value(s). For this sample dataset, however, no difference was introduced.

### Code

```
df_last = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="Y")).last()
out = df_last.diff() / df_last.shift() * 100
```

### Result

```
print(out)

              valeur1                        ...    valeur2                      
category         cat0                  cat2  ...       cat0                  cat2
product            p0         p1         p2  ...         p7         p8         p9
date                                         ...                                 
2000-12-31        NaN        NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN
2001-12-31        NaN  62.000000 -35.869565  ...        NaN -37.113402        NaN
2002-12-31        NaN   8.641975  28.813559  ...        NaN  13.934426        NaN
2003-12-31        NaN -40.909091  19.736842  ...        NaN  30.935252        NaN
2004-12-31        NaN  25.000000 -30.769231  ...        NaN -18.131868        NaN
2005-12-31        NaN -20.000000  57.142857  ...        NaN -18.791946        NaN
2006-12-31        NaN  19.230769 -15.151515  ...        NaN  14.049587        NaN
2007-12-31        NaN  25.806452 -40.476190  ...        NaN  -5.072464        NaN
2008-12-31        NaN  -1.282051   4.000000  ...        NaN  32.824427        NaN
2009-12-31        NaN   7.792208  38.461538  ...        NaN  -9.770115        NaN
2010-12-31        NaN -33.734940 -26.388889  ...        NaN  12.738854        NaN
2011-12-31        NaN  29.090909  83.018868  ...        NaN -12.994350  43.442623
2012-12-31        NaN -19.718310 -40.206186  ...        NaN  -5.194805  13.142857
2013-12-31        NaN  17.543860  34.482759  ...        NaN  12.328767 -19.696970
2014-12-31        NaN   8.955224  23.076923  ...        NaN -22.560976 -18.867925
2015-12-31        NaN  -6.849315 -14.583333  ...        NaN  43.307087  23.255814
2016-12-31        NaN  33.823529  -7.317073  ...        NaN -22.527473  -6.289308
2017-12-31 -22.580645 -35.164835  -2.631579  ...  -8.176101  10.638298 -22.818792
2018-12-31  -6.944444  55.932203   5.405405  ... -30.821918   1.923077  35.652174
2019-12-31  14.925373  -8.695652  -1.282051  ...  70.297030  -6.918239  19.230769
2020-12-31   2.597403   8.333333 -20.779221  ... -28.488372  -6.081081 -17.204301

[21 rows x 20 columns]
```

Comment: Finally I found a solution with : ```lambda x: 100*x.valeur1['2020'].asof('2021')/x.valeur1['2019'].asof('2020')-100``` with find the last non na value before the date inside asof. <br/> Also concerning the first problem I encountered I solve it with an inversion between index and columns ie with ```df.pivot(columns='date', index=['category', 'product'], values=['valeur1', 'valeur2'])```